# jQuery alphabetizes namespaces with multiple separators

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

```
$(document).on('a.b.c', function(e) {
    console.log(e.namespace)
}).trigger('a.b.c')
```

and

```
$(document).on('a.c.b', function(e) {
    console.log(e.namespace)
}).trigger('a.c.b')
```

produce the exact same output:

> b.c

Why is this, and how can I prevent it? I'm using jQuery 1.7.

Comment: I believe `a.b.c` is creating two different namespaces, `b` and `c`, as you can see if you try `.trigger('a.c')` and `.trigger('a.b')` with the above. If you want a namespace called `b.c` can you use `b-c` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event namespaces aren't nested. You're creating two namespaces, `b`, and `c`, with the event `a` in both of them. The order doesn't matter, so jQuery doesn't preserve it. It canonicalizes the event so that if you define handlers for `a.b.c` and `a.c.b` it recognizes that they're actually binding the same event and can put them in the same entry in its internal event binding data.

Comment: Namespaces don't nest. They're like classes. Read the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names